# How to determine whether an NSSearchField/NSTextField has input focus?

Tags: cocoa, macos

How can I determine whether an NSSearchField/NSTextField has input focus?

Comment: my answer was in fact incorrect. I've edited it so that you can remove the checkmark. Please see Greg Titus's answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The previous answer is wrong, because `NSTextField` / `NSSearchField` do not themselves become the first responder and handle edited text. Instead, they use the window's field editor, which is an `NSTextView` that is shared between all fields on the window (since only one of them can have focus at a time).

You need to see if the first responder is an `NSText`, and if so, if the search field / text field is its delegate.

```
NSResponder *firstResponder = [[NSApp keyWindow] firstResponder];
if ([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSText class]] && [(id)firstResponder delegate] == mySearchField) {
    NSLog(@"Yup.");
}
```

Comment: Quite correct about my incorrectness; good answer! (You should've left me a comment.) One small note: you'll need to cast the pointer to the search field, since `delegate` returns `id`.

Comment: I ended up using a different solution to my issue that I felt was better anyways and that didn't require me to know if the NSTextField had input focus, but thank you for your answer and I will definitely note it for future reference. +1

Comment: how do you translate in swift (id)firstResponder delegate = mySearchField

Answer (score 13):

While Greg Titus' answer probably works, I think the following is a better way:

```c
BOOL isFirstResponder = mySearchField.currentEditor == mySearchField.window.firstResponder;
```

Comment: This is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

AppKit uses a “field editor” (which is an `NSTextView`) to handle the actual editing in an `NSTextField` (or an `NSSearchField` or an `NSSecureTextField`). While your text field has keyboard focus for its window, it has the field editor as a subview, and the window's first responder is the field editor.

So in general, you can check whether the text field has a field editor:

```
if textField.currentEditor() != nil {
    // textField has the keyboard focus
} else {
    // textField does not have the keyboard focus
}
```

**However**, when you move the focus out of the text field (by pressing the tab key or clicking in another text field), the text field posts an `NSControl.textDidEndEditingNotification` (Objective-C: `NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification`). If the text field has a delegate, and the delegate implements the `control(_:controlTextDidEndEditing:)` method of the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` protocol, then the delegate method is also called for the notification.

While this notification is being delivered (including calling the delegate method), **the text field still has the field editor as a subview**, and the field editor's delegate is still set to the text field. So if you don't want to consider the text field to still have the keyboard focus while in the notification handler (or delegate method), then testing the field editor will give the wrong answer.

(You might think this is a weird thing to test, because after all AppKit is sending you a notification that the text field is no longer the keyboard focus, so why do you need to ask? But maybe your notification handler calls into some other method that wants to check, and you don't want to have to pass in a flag saying “oh by the way the text field is/isn't the keyboard focus right now”.)

Okay, so anyway, before sending the `NSControl.textDidEndEditingNotification`, AppKit changes the text field's window's first responder. So you can check whether the text field has a field editor, and whether that field editor is the first responder of its window.  While you are handling the `NSControl.textDidEndEditingNotification`, this test will report that the text field doesn't have the keyboard focus.

```
extension NSTextField {
    public var hasKeyboardFocus: Bool {
        guard
            let editor = currentEditor(),
            editor == window?.firstResponder
            else { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I call this method somewhere in my NSSearchFieldDelegate to determine whether the searchbar is in focus?

Comment: Probably, since `NSSearchField` is a subclass of `NSTextField`.

Comment: But where do I use it? I tried using it in `controlTextDidChange`, `controlTextDidEndEditing`, and `controlTextDidBeginEditing`. In all cases it *always* reports that the search field is in focus. The same is true for checking if `textField.currentEditor() == nil` Do I need to sign up for the `NSControl.textDidEndEditingNotification`? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: In my case, I don't need to check at a predetermined time **if** the search field is in focus, I need to be notified **when** the search field comes in and out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

NSTextField uses NSFieldEditor under the hood, you can check `currentEditor` if it is the firstResponder

```
extension NSTextField {
    var isFirstResponder: Bool {
        currentEditor() == window?.firstResponder
    }
}
```